# Why was G1 Soundwave's voice made unique?

Tags: transformers, sound-effects

Some audio manipulation was performed to (nearly?) all the G1 Transformers' voice actor's recorded dialogue, giving the in-universe characters' voices an "inhuman"/otherworldly/mechanical effect. A long time ago, I read that the applied effect was "flanging," but from more recent online, some strongly take the position that "flanging" is not what was used - however the specific effect is not necessarily relevant to this question.

Memory tells me, and recent re-viewing of seasons 1 and 2 seem to confirm that among all the G1 Transformers, Soundwave alone had unique audio manipulation applied to his voice, i.e. the Frank Welker's voice, was

> heavily modulated by a vocoder
>   <sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundwave_(Transformers)</sub>

***Why* was Soundwave unique in this extra (or different from other Transformers') alteration of the voice actor's original voice?**

I think I'm more looking for an out-of-universe explanation, i.e. why the production crew decided to single out Soundwave for this extra special voice; but I'm curious if an in-universe explanation provided the motivation/necessity for the production crew to make this decision.

---

What I've tried: trawling google's search results for variations on "Soundwave voice"; lots of results on how to reproduce the effect with modern technology, fewer results on how it was originally created, but no hits that I could find on *why* Soundwave's voice was unique.

Comment: Because he was supposed to be hi-tech in dealing with sound. It's the same reason that Megatron and Optimus have deep voices and their lackies have higher-pitched voices.

Comment: @Valorum - I often think: some people, having experienced something that resonated with them during their formative years, will in later years try/yearn to find a depth and complexity to that something that wasn't at all considered by the work's author. This sounds like the case here, i.e., it sounds like the creative process was effectively "Soundwave is the 'sound guy,' so let's see what cool sound effects we can add to his voice" and nothing intrinsically deeper(?) If that can be cited/attested to, that sounds like an answer to me.